# Can a Core Data Relationship Have Attributes

Tags: mysql, macos, core-data, swift3

I'm porting a MySQL database to Core Data for a Mac OS app. I have two many to many tables in my database. In addition to containing the foreign keys, there are a few data columns. Is it possible to add attributes to a many to many relationship in Core Data? It doesn't look like it to me. My fallback is to replicate the linkage table in Core Data. Are there any problems doing this?

An example: 
A record has one or more artists performing on it.
An artist performs on zero or more records.
The linkage table row contains a foreign key for the record, a foreign key for the artist, the instruments the player performed with, and a notes column that adds additional information such has which track the artist performed on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: relationships themselves cannot have attributes.  And you are on the right track in modelling the linking table as an intermediate entity.  This approach is alluded to in the [CoreData Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html) section on "Modelling a relationship based on its semantics".  In their case, they model a (reflexive) many-many relationship from `Person` to `Person` using an intermediate `FriendsInfo` entity with a `ranking` attribute.

In your example, you might have a `Record` entity, an `Artist` entity, and an intermediate `Appearance` entity.  The `Appearance` entity would have attributes for Instruments and Notes, and (to-one) relationships to `Record` and `Artist` (each with a to-many inverse).

The slight downside is that you have to create the `Appearance` object in order to link a `Record` object and an `Artist` object, rather than just adding them to the relevant relationship.  You will also have to watch for uniqueness of the combination of `Record`/`Artist`, if that's important to you: by default there could be many `Appearances` for the same `Record` and `Artist`.